# Is it possible to use MobX without React?

Tags: javascript, mobx

I like MobX.
I would like to use it in native JavaScript.
I tried adding the CDN https://cdnjs.com/libraries/mobx
Then I tried writing a class with MobX Syntax:

```
class MyStore {
  @observable data = 'foo'
}
const myStore = new MyStore();
```

but I get errors:

```
SyntaxError: illegal character
```

for the `@` and:

```
ReferenceError: exports is not defined
```

from inside `mobx.js` file.

So it does not seem to be possible without React and without Blunding/Transpiler, is it?
If not are there alternatives?

Thank you!

Comment: You don't need React but you do need Babel (`babel-preset-mobx` preset) if you want decorator syntax https://mobx.js.org/best/decorators.html

Answer (score 4):

Yes, you can use MobX without React, but in your example you used decorators syntax, which belong to ES.Next, and is not natively supported by the browser, and requires a transpiler (Babel, for example).

If you want to use MobX directly in your browser without decorators, these instructions can be useful for you: https://mobx.js.org/best/decorators.html

Answer (score 4):

As @someone235 said, it is possible.

to show you, here is an example without any react in it: https://jsfiddle.net/Lrt9pky4/

This is the code, although i can't enable decorators in SO so the below example doesn't work. the link does work.

```js
const {observable, computed, autorun} = mobx;
class MyStore {
  @observable data = 'foo'
}
const myStore = new MyStore();      
autorun(()=> {
console.log(myStore.data);
document.getElementById('log').innerHTML += myStore.data + "<br />"
})

myStore.data = 'bar'
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/mobx@3/lib/mobx.umd.js"></script>
<body>
  Log
  <hr/>
  <div id="log">
  </div>
</body>
```

You can use autorun and observe/intercept methods to receive notifications from changes, but you'd have to write all the other code yourself. (to react on these changes properly, phun intended).

Answer (score 2):

No need for decorators. You can try the Mobx 4 approach:

```
import { decorate, observable} from "mobx"
class MyStore {
  data = 'foo'
}
decorate(City, {
    data: observable,
})
const myStore = new MyStore();
```

more details here https://medium.com/@mweststrate/mobx-4-better-simpler-faster-smaller-c1fbc08008da